# Maven error during build from Command Prompt

Tags: maven

During my build with maven I am seeing the below error. As per my understanding it is missing the testng-5.9-jdk15.jar. I specifically downloaded it and put in my repository, but I am still seeing the below error. Any suggestions

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx:xxxx:jar:16.06.30.9:
Failure to find org.testng:testng:jar:jdk15:5.9
```

Comment: Can you show us the pom.xml

Comment: You let Maven do the download...

Comment: Had to make the classifier field blank when uploading the jar to my central repo. the jar was being name... testng-5.9-jdk15.jdk15.jar instead of testng-5.9-jdk15.jar. Was able to resolve the issues.